# How to switch the captions on youtube video?

Tags: youtube, caption

For our platform we need to embed the video linked to youtube and provide captions only for one specific language. So in general the video in YouTube has 10 languages, but I need to have only french captions always on when the browser's interface language is french. Other languages "on request".

I have tried to append cc_load_policy=1 and it switches on the caption, but i need only french and only for french users

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XoRM" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google has it's own IFrame Player API, and on their website you can change the player parameters, to customize your IFrame Embed code: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

I recommend you read up on "YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds": https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference